# record delete error in database mdf in visual studio

Tags: c#, database

I have records having same id. I am trying  to delete them but getting error:

> no rows were deleted
>
> a problem occurred attempting to delete row 9
> error source Microsoft visual studio.Datatools
> error message the row values updated or deleted do no make the unique or
> they alter multiple rows

Comment: dear its visually not have a code

Comment: i created a database in project. then table write click table select show table data then i try to delete record here and got error

Comment: Can you tell us full error message

Comment: "no rows were deleted

a problem occurred attempting to delete row 9.                   error source: Microsoft visual studio.Datatools                 error message: the row values updated or deleted either  do no make the row unique or they alter multiple rows(3)                                                              correct the error and atemp to delete again or press to cancel changes"    this is complete error. site not allowing me to attach pic.

Answer (score 2):

May be you have not included a primary key and there may be some duplicate records. Try adding primary key to your table.

I have got some explanation [HERE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6ca9ab1f-00b3-450e-9c3f-ce00a6d22b4c/row-will-not-update-or-delete-using-database-explorer-vwd-express)

> In SQL Server, there MUST be a way to uniquely identify a row for a
> DELETE or UPDATE action. IF the row(s) you are attempting to DELETE
> are duplicate to other rows, you will not be allowed to delete them.
>
> You options are to create either an IDENTITY field in the table, or a
> PRIMARY KEY -both of which will uniquely identify the row -allowing
> deletes to occur.

**UPDATE:**

You could create a new column, and set the column to be an IDENTITY.

> Alter Table_Names
> Add Id_new Int Identity(1, 1)
> Go

When you change the table, all existing rows will be assigned an unique value for this column, and then you will be able to use that new value in your delete action.

Comment: i add primary key in database when i save i got error because record have same ids i want to delete them but cant. getting the error

Comment: Please see my update above

Comment: but database not allow me to add because if i add a row with primary key the already existed records will contain its value nul so it no allows to add if i add a row which is not identical the i got the above mention error. i try to attach it with sql managment studio but i got version error database is developed in old version

Comment: have u tried adding identity column? if not see my update